# How to display C2DM message as a push notification (recived on onMessage() function of GCMIntentService class)

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-c2dm

Hi all i implemented C@DM in my app based on the tutorial provided by 
http://avilyne.com/?p=267.It works but my problem is i only getting the message in my activity that set on a text view.But i want it out side the app even if app is not working and when i click this i want to extract a number from this and want to Launch a particular activity(Not home activity) and when back press it come to home activity.

My GCMIntentService class is like this (I added gcm.jar to my project)

```
package com.lejin.myapp;

/**

 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String PROJECT_ID = "76973814590";

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService()
    {
        super(PROJECT_ID);
        Log.d(TAG, "GCMIntentService init");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onError(Context ctx, String sError) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + sError);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context ctx, Intent intent) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Message Received");

        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

        sendGCMIntent(ctx, message);

    }


    private void sendGCMIntent(Context ctx, String message) {

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION");

        broadcastIntent.putExtra("gcm", message);

        ctx.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context ctx, String regId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // send regId to your server
        Log.d(TAG, regId);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context ctx, String regId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // send notification to your server to remove that regId

    }
}
```

I recived that messsage using broad cast reciver on my activity

```
 package com.lejin.myapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // This is the project id generated from the Google console when
    // you defined a Google APIs project.
    private static final String PROJECT_ID = "76973814590";

    // This tag is used in Log.x() calls
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    // This string will hold the lengthy registration id that comes
    // from GCMRegistrar.register()
    private String regId = "";

    // These strings are hopefully self-explanatory
    private String registrationStatus = "Not yet registered";
    private String broadcastMessage = "No broadcast message";

    // This intent filter will be set to filter on the string "GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION"
    IntentFilter gcmFilter;

    // textviews used to show the status of our app's registration, and the latest
    // broadcast message.
    TextView tvRegStatusResult;
    TextView tvBroadcastMessage;

    // This broadcastreceiver instance will receive messages broadcast
    // with the action "GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION" via the gcmFilter

    // A BroadcastReceiver must override the onReceive() event.
    private BroadcastReceiver gcmReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            broadcastMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("gcm");

            if (broadcastMessage != null) {
                // display our received message
                tvBroadcastMessage.setText(broadcastMessage);
            }
        }
    };

    // Reminder that the onCreate() method is not just called when an app is first opened,
    // but, among other occasions, is called when the device changes orientation.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvBroadcastMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_message);
        tvRegStatusResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_reg_status_result);

        // Create our IntentFilter, which will be used in conjunction with a
        // broadcast receiver.
        gcmFilter = new IntentFilter();
        gcmFilter.addAction("GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION");

        registerClient();
    }

    // This registerClient() method checks the current device, checks the
    // manifest for the appropriate rights, and then retrieves a registration id
    // from the GCM cloud.  If there is no registration id, GCMRegistrar will
    // register this device for the specified project, which will return a
    // registration id.
    public void registerClient() {

        try {
            // Check that the device supports GCM (should be in a try / catch)
            GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

            // Check the manifest to be sure this app has all the required
            // permissions.
            GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

            // Get the existing registration id, if it exists.
            regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

            if (regId.equals("")) {

                registrationStatus = "Registering...";

                tvRegStatusResult.setText(registrationStatus);

                // register this device for this project
                GCMRegistrar.register(this, PROJECT_ID);
                regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),regId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                registrationStatus = "Registration Acquired";

                // This is actually a dummy function.  At this point, one
                // would send the registration id, and other identifying
                // information to your server, which should save the id
                // for use when broadc
                // asting messages.
                sendRegistrationToServer();

            } else {

                registrationStatus = "Already registered";

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            registrationStatus = e.getMessage();

        }

        Log.d(TAG, registrationStatus);
        tvRegStatusResult.setText(registrationStatus);

        // This is part of our CHEAT.  For this demo, you'll need to
        // capture this registration id so it can be used in our demo web
        // service.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),regId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, regId);

    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer() {
        // This is an empty placeholder for an asynchronous task to post the
        // registration
        // id and any other identifying information to your server.
    }

    // If the user changes the orientation of his phone, the current activity
    // is destroyed, and then re-created.  This means that our broadcast message
    // will get wiped out during re-orientation.
    // So, we save the broadcastmessage during an onSaveInstanceState()
    // event, which is called prior to the destruction of the activity.

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // If the user changes the orientation of his phone, the current activity
    // is destroyed, and then re-created.  This means that our broadcast message
    // will get wiped out during re-orientation.
    // So, we save the broadcastmessage during an onSaveInstanceState()
    // event, which is called prior to the destruction of the activity.
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        savedInstanceState.putString("BroadcastMessage", broadcastMessage);

    }

    // When an activity is re-created, the os generates an onRestoreInstanceState()
    // event, passing it a bundle that contains any values that you may have put
    // in during onSaveInstanceState()
    // We can use this mechanism to re-display our last broadcast message.

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        broadcastMessage = savedInstanceState.getString("BroadcastMessage");
        tvBroadcastMessage.setText(broadcastMessage);

    }

    // If our activity is paused, it is important to UN-register any
    // broadcast receivers.
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        unregisterReceiver(gcmReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    // When an activity is resumed, be sure to register any
    // broadcast receivers with the appropriate intent
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(gcmReceiver, gcmFilter);

    }

    // There are no menus for this demo app.  This is just
    // boilerplate code.
    // NOTE the call to GCMRegistrar.onDestroy()
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

I want to show this message as like normal push notification shown in whats app or other common apps and need to open a specific activity (not home activity) based on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is, modify your `onMessage` function in order to create a notification (push notifications is a different concept from app notifications) for your app instead of calling `sendGCMIntent`.

Got from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html), you should do something like the following:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!");
// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, TheActivityYouWantToOpen.class);

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class); //to allow you to use back button
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
        0,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// my_notification_idallows you to update the notification later on.
mNotificationManager.notify(my_notification_id, mBuilder.build());
```

Notification id is just an integer you may use to update an existing notification.

Hope it helps

Comment: hi zozelfelfo  this works fine thank you.But my push message is big and it only show one line so is it possible to show full message in notification window it self.

Comment: In the link I have posted it talks about Expanded notifications aswell and how to handle compatibility (they only work in android 4.1+)